# Location of log folder in chef workstation

Tags: chef-infra

I would like to know where exactly the logs are located for chef workstation. I'm trying to bootstrap a node and it just gives the following message.

/usr/bin/knife bootstrap y.y.y.y -x root -P ****** -N i-77378d_79 -c /opt/cloudone/1/CHEF/1/knife.rb
Bootstrapping Chef on y.y.y.y

There are no errors and no stack trace mentioned or pointed out.

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Knife does not write to a log file. Add `-l debug` for verbose output.

Comment: Additionally the "bootstrap" command executes on the remote machine over ssh.